# How many servers does Stack Overflow use?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, architecture

Stack Overflow is very fast.

I am just curious about how many servers are needed to support such a big number of hits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are [some glamor shots](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/new-stack-overflow-server-glamour-shots/) of the servers.

[Here are some stats](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/12/server-hosting-rent-vs-buy/) regarding the cost.

And if you wanna read more about the servers at stackoverflow, [check this link (server tag on the blog.](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/server/)

Comment: also: http://blog.serverfault.com/

Comment: When editing your answer I ran into a captcha.  One of the words was *Wage*.

Comment: @jjinguy what a coincidence, all of my captchas are "jinguy is awesome"